# Replace string with anchor tags in angualrjs1

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a string and I want to replace first ## with open a tag and second ## with close a tag. How Can I get this with regex or with something else.

Suppose :

```
var string = "Hello World, ##How are you##, Today, i am fine";
result should be "Hello World <a href='javascript:void(0)'>How are you</a>,Today, i am fine"
```

Comment: `string.replace("##","<a href='javascript:void(0)'>").replace("##","</a>")`; could do a while loop until there are no more `##` appearing

Comment: Thanks @AlekseySolovey

Comment: to be robust, you can have a counter, where if you see `##` odd number of times, the counter is 1, if number of `##` is even, then counter goes back to 0. That way you will know if the tag can be closed with `</a>`

Answer (score 1):

You asked for a regular expression matching this so here's one:

```
/##([^}]+)##
```

Here's an example substituting text based on the above expression, similar to what you asked for:

https://regex101.com/r/HFkyjx/1

I'm going to leave the exact code writing to you :) You should be able to figure it out with string replace.